# panda dataframe problem in python pd.DataFrame({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> I want to create a 2-dimensional tagged data frame. But I every time
>   get a different error.
>
> I use the data as in the picture. sql server query output

[docs in json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab8qo.jpg)

**codes I wrote below**

```
docs = json.loads(docs)
classes = ['internet', 'arıza', 'kesinti', 'fatura', 'fatura', 
            'telefon', 'spor', 'ekonomi']

#df_docs = pd.DataFrame({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})
#df_docs= pd.Series([docs, classes], index=['Dokuman','Sinif'])
#df_docs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(docs)
#df_docs = pd.DataFrame({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})
```

how do I set the data frame here?

```
df_docs = pd.DataFrame({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})
```

get error when I use this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the number of records in the docs is not equal to the number of
>   records in the classes, so I am getting the error

**the problem has improved**